# Crossing the French/Italian (Chamonix/Cormayeur) border via cable car

Tags: france, transportation, italy, borders, gondolas-and-cable-cars

My partner and I will be travelling through Chamonix on the 25th of April, and we were wanting to travel via cable car through to Courmayeur. Are there cable cars that allow us to travel from Chamonix to Courmayeur operating on that day?

If they are not operating, is there any other form of transport that will allow us to make this journey over the mountain?

From what I can tell on this link: http://www.compagniedumontblanc.co.uk/en/site-overview/aiguille-du-midi/timetables It's possible that the cable car we need to take only operates from the end of June to the start of September?

Answer (score 6):

Correct, the panoramic cable car (Helbronner-Aiguille du Midi) is open only in summer, so the only transport option outside July-September is the bus through the Mont Blanc tunnel.

For the Courmayeur-Chamonix direction it is possible to ski from Helbronner station down the Glacier du Geant, linking up with the Vallee Blanche to finish in Montenvers, but only if you have extensive backcountry experience and are willing to hire a guide for the day.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also planning a similar trip in the summer. English - not my native language, so I do not fully understand what you want to do. Permitted to cross the bus on the Mont Blanc tunnel, or you will definitely go to traverse from the top of the mountains? If you possible way through a tunnel here.
http://www.chamonix.com/transport-in-the-valley,13,en.html

If second  case
http://www.montebianco.com/tariffe.php

> Basse saison  du 1 décembre 2011 au 31 mai 2013  y compris l´entrée à
>   l´Exposition de Cristaux